# What is a bifurcation point?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, mathematical-modeling

Given a density dependent difference equation, $N_{n+1}=N_{n}e^{r[1-(N_{n}/K)]}=f(N_{n})$, with $r > 0$ and $K > 0$. I've found that the equilibria are at $N^*=K$ or $0$. Discussing their linear stability as a function of $r$, there is a bifurcation point at $r=2$. What does it mean by bifurcation point?